# How to append string pointer with many strings from recursive function call in C

Tags: concatenation

I am having a problem concatenating strings collected from BST nodes  based on some condition. I have to use a recursive function call for that and put spacers between them. I am using `char**` to make it easy. The realloc doesn't concatenate well, it keeps trash values at the beginning of `str` but it adds the appended strings well. How can I fix or upgrade this code?

```
void _buildLine(wordT* root, int lineNo, char** str)
{
    int count = lineNo;
    
    if (!root)
        return;
    {
         _buildLine(root->left, lineNo, str);
        QNODE* temp = root->queL_No;         // BST has queue
        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            if (temp->L_number == lineNo)
            {
                char strAppend[100];
                char spacer[3] = ", ";
                strcpy(strAppend, root->data);

                //**str is allocated before function call already**
                //** str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))**
                *str = (char*)realloc(*str, (strlen(strAppend) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcat(*str, strAppend);
                *str = (char*)realloc(*str, strlen(spacer) + 1) * sizeof(char));
                strcat(*str, spacer);
                break;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        free(temp);
            
         _buildLine(root->right, lineNo, str);
    }
    
}
```

After function ends, I got this output
"═════²²²²boat, row, your, " which suppose to be "boat, row, your, "

Comment: 2nd arg to realloc() is the **total** size in bytes, not the additional size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Will try to fix that and see.